# How to programmatically set the "Retain Indefinitely" field when a build successfully completes?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I'm looking for a way to set the retain indefinitely field of a build when it completes.

Maybe using a PowerShell script as a build step?

Comment: Are you using Release Management? It seems according to this post that it is set automatically for all builds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26259004/release-management-sets-builds-to-retain-indefinitely There is even a answere with how to mod the buildscript to remove "Retain Indefinitely". Maybe you could utilize that mod to undo it, to enable it?

Comment: Adding Vs-Team-Services tag as it uses the same build infrastructure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the ["Build Updating Tasks" extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=richardfennellBM.BM-VSTS-BuildUpdating-Tasks). It contains a Build Retention task. It does exactly what you need. You do need to be on Update 3 of TFS if I'm not mistaking.

Comment: Semi works, but I had a 401 unauthorized exception, but I've commented on this, and given the author feedback.

Answer (score 2):

For the benefit of searchers using vNext builds, you can use a Powershell script to do this.

You will need to 'Allow scripts to access OAuth token' in the buid options.

```
$buildId = $env:BUILD_BUILDID # the currently running build
"Build ID: $buildId"

$keepforever = @{
    keepforever='true'
}

$jsonKeepForever = $keepforever | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100

$uriForBuildUpdate = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID)/_apis/build/builds/" + $buildID + "?api-version=2.0"

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriForBuildUpdate -Method Patch -Body $jsonKeepForever -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{ Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" }

Write-Verbose "Result: $result" -Verbose

"********************************"
"Build set to retain indefinitely"
"********************************"
```